# Calculate Integral using Divergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

If $F = x\ i + y\ j $, calculate $ \iint F \cdot n d\sigma$  over the part of the surface $z = 4-x^2-y^2$ that is above the xy-plane, by applying the divergence theorem to the volume bounded by the surface and the piece that it cuts out of the xy-plane.
Hint: What is $F\cdot n$ on the xy-plane?

My Attempt:

The surface is a circle of radius 2 in the xy plane.  I am unsure of what the value of the normal vector is and how I can find it. Would you just take the gradient of the surface z and dot product it with F? What will $d\sigma$ be when I am integrating?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the components of $F$ are only in the $xy$-plane. The normal vector to a surface at a point on the surface is the vector perpendicular to the surface at that point. What does that imply about $F \cdot n$ on the $xy$-plane?

Comment: The normal vector will be in the $k$ direction, but since there is no force in the $k$ direction, $F\cdot n$ will be 0.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now look at the half-dome that comprises the rest of the surface, and think about F at symmetric points on the surface in all 4 quadrants. If you like, consider each component of F separately.

Comment: On second thought, belay my last comment on the half-dome part of the surface. That won't help much. Been too long since I've done this.

Comment: So I should use divergence theorem to do triple integral of divF dV?

Comment: @karan4496 Pretty much. Note that div(F) is a constant, so the triple integral will just give you a constant times the volume.